# Dose chinese need wordpiece?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp

I want to use Chinese bert model. In tokenization.py, I fond WordpieceTokenizer function(https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/tokenization.py), but I don't think it is needed to use wordpiece for chinese, because the miminal unit of chinese is character.

WordpieceTokenizer is just for english text, am I right?

Comment: What is a "token"? What is a minimal unit of any language? =)
BTW, WordPiece isn't open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the README:

> We use character-based tokenization for Chinese, and WordPiece tokenization for all other languages.

However, from the [Multilingual README](https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/multilingual.md#tokenization) (emphasis added):

> Because Chinese (and Japanese Kanji and Korean Hanja) does not have whitespace characters, we add spaces around every character in the CJK Unicode range **before applying WordPiece.**

So WordPiece is presumably run on the whole sentence, though it would only matter for sentences that contained non-Chinese characters. So to run the code as-is you would want WordPiece.

However, to clarify:

- WordPiece is not just for English, it can be used on any language and in practice is used on many
- Whether single character-based tokenization for Chinese is the best decision is debated
- WordPiece is not available outside Google, [SentencePiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) could be used as a replacement (though I think the BERT code might have a pretrained model)